# Is there a way to make this SQL query more efficient?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, query-optimization

I am joining 3 tables with the same column, but the query is taking too long to complete.

Besides date parameters, what can I do to make this more efficient?

Should I join before summing?

```
SELECT 
    extract(year from a.stream_date) year,
    b.mdm.artist_name,
    b.mdm.title,
    b.kpi_label.label_name,
    a.isrc,
    SUM(a.youtube.vevo_streams) vevo,
    SUM(a.youtube.shorts_player_streams) shorts,
    SUM(a.youtube.direct_streams) direct, 
    SUM(a.youtube.ugc_streams) ugc ,
    SUM(c.youtube_revenue) AS Revenue
FROM 
    `umg-kpi.streams.kpi_streams` AS a
JOIN
    `umg-kpi.metadata.product_isrc` AS b ON a.isrc = b.isrc 
JOIN
    `umg-kpi.consumption.track_streams` AS c ON c.isrc =a.isrc
WHERE
    b.kpi_label.label_name = 'UMLE'
    AND a.stream_date BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2022-12-31'
    AND c.stream_date BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2022-12-31'
GROUP BY
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5
ORDER BY
    Revenue DESC
LIMIT 200
```

Comment: Hi @florida_man007, can you provide sample input and sample output?

Answer (score 0):

Use indexes: Create indexes on the columns that are used in the WHERE clause, JOIN conditions, and GROUP BY clause. This will help the query planner to quickly find the relevant data.